# .htaccess rewrite .php extension and 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've been banging my head for the past couple hours, searching through past questions and trying to figure out how to do this.

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This works great - all of my .php files now have no extension.

So, example.com/news.php => example.com/news

Now, I tried setting up 301 redirects in numerous ways, but none of them seem to work. What I'd like to get is the following:

example.com/about/ => example.com/about/our-story
example.com/work/ => example.com/

I've tried the following code:

```
Redirect 301 /about/ /about/our-story
```

And I even tried this, but no luck:

```
RewriteRule ^/work/$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

But I'm sure that because of the rewrite, it's just not working. I guess I just can't wrap my head around this. I've been troubleshooting this site all weekend and my brain is fried. I'm sure the answer is right in front of me, but if someone could help guide me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use ^/ in htaccess.
Try this rule

```
RewriteRule ^work/?$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```